# Best practice redux actions with flowtype?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I want to write redux with flowtype, but I have questions about how to do that.

### Redux with Flowtype

```js
type ActionType =
  | 'A'
  | 'B'
  ;

// A generic type conforming to Flux Standard Action
type ActionT<A, P> = {|
  type: A,
  payload?: P | Error,
  error?: boolean,
  meta?: mixed
|};

type Action =
  | ActionT<'A', string>
  | ActionT<'B', number>
  ;

const error: Error = new Error('wrong');
const info = { href: '...' };

// ---- valid actions with flowtype ----
const action1: Action = {type: 'A', payload: 'hello' };
const action2: Action = {type: 'A', payload: error, error: true };  // The 'payload' could be an error.
const action3: Action = {type: 'A', payload: 'hello', meta: info };  // We can have 'meta'.

// ---- invalid actions with flowtype ----
const actionNG1: Action = {type: 'C', payload: 'hello' };  // Wrong 'type' value. The type 'C' is not allowed.
const actionNG2: Action = {type: 'B', payload: 'hello' };  // Wrong value type of 'payload'. It should be a number.
const actionNG3: Action = {type: 'A', payload: 'hello', threshold: 3 };  // Extra property 'threshold' is not allowed. It should conform to type ActionT.
```

- I use `ActionType` instead of constants to check the valid `type` values.
- The type `ActionT` conforms [Flux Standard Action](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action) to ensure the structure of Redux actions.
- The type `Action` declares the concrete types for all actions that we'll use in our App.

#### Question 1: how to ensure the first type passed to `ActionT` would be the type of `ActionType` (or at least, should be a `string` type)?

For example, adding a new type `'C'` in not allowed, because `ActionType` only accepts `'A'` and `'B'`.

```js
type ActionType =
  | 'A'
  | 'B'
  ;

type Action =
  | ActionT<'A', string>
  | ActionT<'B', number>
  | ActionT<'C', number>  // Should Raise an error
  ;
```

Does it make sense?

#### Question 2: how to write the reducers (and `thunk`) with flowtype and Immutable.js?

I've written a buildReducer to bind to a initial state.

```js
type Action =
  | ActionT<'SELECT_COUNTRY', string>
  ;

const buildReducer = (initialState, reducerMap) =>
  (state = initialState, action) => {
    const reducer = reducerMap[action.type];
    return (reducer) ? reducer(state, action) : state;
  };

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  selectedCountry: 'US'
})

const reducers = {
  ['SELECT_COUNTRY']: (state, action) => {
    // how to know the type of payload is string type?
    // how to ensure that `state.set(...)` gets right type of the value for the key?
    return state.set('selectedCountry', action.payload)
  }
}

const appReducer = buildReducer(initialState, reducers)
```

How can I check the `payload` type in the `reducers` for action type `SELECT_COUNTRY` with flowtype ?

How can I apply the payload value to the `immutable` state with flowtype check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer question 1, you can use bounded polymorphism

```
// A generic type conforming to Flux Standard Action
type ActionT<A: ActionType, P> = {|
  type: A,
  payload?: P | Error,
  error?: boolean,
  meta?: mixed
|};
```

Notice how we bound the generic parameter `A` to `ActionType`

To answer question 2, you have to make sure to pull in immutable-js types here: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow and then type your reducer functions.